# MYSQL Key partitioning - Uneven distribution of data

Tags: partitioning

We are facing issues with uneven distribution of data across key partitions. The partition key is a UUID column. When we create 36 partitions, only 9 partitions are populated and when we create 100 partitions, only 25 partitions get populated. What could be the cause of that ? Is there some issue with MYSQL key partition while working with UUIDs?

Also, is there a way to customize the MYSQL key partitioning implementation so that we could use something like mod(crc32(),36)

Thanks for your help. 
Prikshat

Comment: What generator are you using to get the UUID? Google UUID Sparse index

Comment: We are using Java UUID Generator

Comment: If UUID's are not totally random, but are for instance commonly generated based an a MAC address in the generating server(s), you get partially similar UUIDś, so, also uneven distribution in the index. While it theoretically increases the chances of collision, you might be better of instructing your `UUID` generator to NOT use this data but to generate at total random.